# ¿Cómo puedo mirar el calendario completo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-datepicker

Todo el funcionamiento está ok. Pero cuando abro el calendario de datepicker está abierto, queda debajo de los `inputs` text.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De que forma puedo ponerlo frente a ellos?

Comment: Es mucho mas fácil si compartes el código, para usarlo como base en la respuesta. Supongo que quizas puedas corregirlo con z-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para cambiar la visibilidad debes jugar con los z-index (propiedad css). Estos hacen justamente lo que dices: añaden más o menos profundidad a un elemento. Si le pones un z-index mayor al calendario que a los inputs, éste aparecerá delante.

La solución fue z-index de css:

> La propiedad CSS z-index indica el z-order de un elemento y sus descendientes. Cuando varios elementos se superponen, z-order determina cuales cubren a otros. Un elemento con mayor z-index generalmente cubre a otro menor.

```
<div class="form-group" style="z-index: 1">
    <label>Fecha de corte:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control />
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente! se lo aplique al div del calentario y funcionó. Gracias!